# Decimal exemption using Catch

Tags: c#, if-statement, try-catch, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator that Display an error message when user try to use A decimal value, I'm trying to use Catch to Exemption a Decimal value and then give the user and error message like "Decimal value is invalid"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter an equation:");
        string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        string[] terms = input.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '+', '-', '*', '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(terms[0]);
        if (input[0] == '-')
        {
            firstNumber = -firstNumber;
            input = input.Remove(0, 1);
        }
        input = input.Remove(0, terms[0].Length).Trim();

        char op = input[0];
        input = input.Remove(0, 1).Trim();

        int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(terms[1]);
        if (input[0] == '-')
            secondNumber = -secondNumber;

        int result = 0;

        if (op == '+')
            try
            {
                result = (firstNumber + secondNumber);
            }
            catch(FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry cannot accept decimals");
            }

        else if (op == '-')
            try
            {
                result = (firstNumber - secondNumber);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

        else if (op == '*')
            try
            {
                result = (firstNumber * secondNumber);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

        else if (op == '/')
            try
            {
                result = (firstNumber / secondNumber);
            }
            catch
            {
            }


        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

> I'm trying to make a calculator that Display an error message when user try to use A decimal value, I'm trying to use Catch to Exemption a Decimal value and then give the user and error message like "Decimal value is invalid"
>
> I'm trying to make a calculator that Display an error message when user try to use A decimal value, I'm trying to use Catch to Exemption a Decimal value and then give the user and error message like "Decimal value is invalid"
>
> I'm trying to make a calculator that Display an error message when user try to use A decimal value, I'm trying to use Catch to Exemption a Decimal value and then give the user and error message like "Decimal value is invalid"

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Sounds like you want int.TryParse https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0  or string.Contains https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0

Comment: You need to put your try..catch around the `Convert.ToInt32` as this is what throws the exception, Also, you may want to look at int.TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly need only integral number to calculate - you may add a check before `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
if (terms[0].Contains(".") || terms[0].Contains(","))
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, only integral numbers supported!");
```

or wrap `Convert.ToInt32` into `try-catch`:{

```
try 
{
    firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(terms[0]);
}
catch 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("You inputed not a number or not integral number!");
}
```

Or you can use `double` or `float` or `decimal` types instead of `int` and have no such troubles:

```
double firstNumber = double.Parse(terms[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// or
float firstNumber = float.Parse(terms[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// or
decimal firstNumber = decimal.Parse(terms[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` used to handle dot `.` or comma `,` separators, but i prefer to add comma replacement with dot (`terms[0].Replace(",", ".")` to have correct parse.
Also you can wrap it into `try-catch` too, but there exists provided `TryParse` methods for that purposes:

```
double.TryParse(terms[0].Replace(",", "."), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double firstNumber);
// or
float.TryParse(terms[0].Replace(",", "."), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out float firstNumber);
// or
decimal.TryParse(terms[0].Replace(",", "."), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimal firstNumber);
```

Also you can manipulate with result value through `System.Math.Round` method to get nearest integral value:

```
double firstNumber = 0.5;
double secondNumber = 0.6;
double result1 = (firstNumber - secondNumber); // Will give you 1.1 (double type)
double result2 = Math.Round(firstNumber - secondNumber); // Will give you 1 (double type).
int result3 = (int)Math.Round(firstNumber - secondNumber); // Will give you 1 (int type)
```